# Helm: the range function is not keeping the input values in order as expected?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates, helm3

I know, the dictionary is processed based on order. However, for some process purpose I need to run the certain process in some order. (Since native k8s wont support cronjobs in order, I am doing it in entry point of single pod).
Below is my values.yaml

```
batches:
  evaluate_events:
    ev-cron-3:
      populate_data:
        event-name: "Populate  Data process"
        business-process: "Generic"
        rule-type: "Identification"
      auth_export:
        event-name: "Auth Export Ruleset"
        business-process: "Generic"
        rule-type: "Constraint Satisfaction"
      new_document_attached:
        event-name: "New Document Attached"
        business-process: "Generic"
        rule-type: "Constraint Satisfaction"
```

My code inv k8s yaml:

```
{{- range $event, $data := $.Values.batches }}
{{- range $key, $cron := $data }
{{- range $jobname, $inputs := $cron }}
            - '{{ $event }} {{- range $args, $val := $inputs }} --{{ $args }} "{{ $val }}" {{- end }}'
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Expected output: Same order as in values.yaml

```
- 'evaluate_events --business-process "Generic" --event-name "Populate  Data process" --rule-type "Identification"'
- 'evaluate_events --business-process "Generic" --event-name "Auth Export Ruleset" --rule-type "Constraint Satisfaction"'
- 'evaluate_events --business-process "Generic" --event-name "New Document Attached" --rule-type "Constraint Satisfaction"'
```

Actual Output: Not in the order as per values.yaml

```
- 'evaluate_events --business-process "Generic" --event-name "Auth Export Ruleset" --rule-type "Constraint Satisfaction"'
- 'evaluate_events --business-process "Generic" --event-name "New Document Attached" --rule-type "Constraint Satisfaction"'
- 'evaluate_events --business-process "Generic" --event-name "Populate  Data process" --rule-type "Identification"'
```

Needed, if there is anyone handled such situation? and How this can be achieved?

Comment: `$cron` should be is a map so `the elements will be visited in sorted key order.`. From: https://pkg.go.dev/text/template. Try to rename: `step1_populate, step2_auth, step3_newdoc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a YAML map object in your `values.yaml`.  This consists of pairs of keys and values, but not necessarily in any order.  You probably want a YAML list instead:

```yaml
- arg: event-name
  value: Populate  Data process
- arg: business-process
  value: Generic
- arg: rule-type
  value: Identification
```

Then you can iterate through the list (not the map) using `range`:

```
- '{{ $event }}
{{- range $inputs }} --{{ .arg }} "{{ .value }}"{{- end -}}
'
```

Several places in Kubernetes have lists with `name` fields for pretty much exactly this reason, and you might also consider using this approach higher in your values structure.  If you control the application itself, you also may find it easier to pass these settings as environment variables rather than command-line arguments, since constructing a command string as you show can be syntactically a little tricky.

Comment: I Totally agree.. we are pushing towards not to mess entrypoint in helm, This was some kind of alternative work.. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I disagree. According to [this](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/values/#consider-how-users-will-use-your-values) chapter in Helm's Best Practices, map representation of values is more preferred as it makes using `--set` much easier. Helm devs contradict themselves by not supporting keys order (or at least !!omap type) in values.yaml